# Facebook user rss feed ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, rss

How to get rss feed from facebook?
I have read all the previous discussions but none of them solved my issue.
Can we still get rss fedd from facebook or facebook has stopped this feature?

I am trying to use

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=XXXXXXXXX
```

url but i am getting 404 page not found error.

Comment: That feature has been removed a while ago.

Comment: Is this feature available for twitter??....

Comment: @CodeGuru: Twitter introduced REST APIs provide programmatic access to read and write Twitter data. Create a new Tweet, read user profile and follower data, and more. The REST API identifies Twitter applications and users using OAuth; responses are in JSON format. https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rss feeds is no longer valid. They have introduced graph-api to get the feed of posts.

Please see the details here: [graph-api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/feed)

Comment: that is the user feed, you should replace it with a link to the page feed in the api reference.